# Cannot take screen shots of my Android phone from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, android

I'm trying to connect my HTC Magic to take screenshots on Windows 7 but's it's not getting detected by [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) application.

Windows 7 seems to list the Android Phone among the "devices and printers", I tried to update the drivers to the ones withing the SDK and not the default from Microsoft, but nothing seems to work also.

Running the application as administrator didn't help either.

What do you suggest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

USB Debugging must be enabled on the phone, under Settings - Applications - Development. Otherwise you'll get what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Does `adb` work?

You might not have all the required drivers.

The easiest way to get them is to install HTC Sync.

The USB driver from the Google Developer site doesn't work, or at least it doesn't on HTC Desire.

Answer (score 0):

There is another program you might want to try to take screenshots.

It is called MyPhoneExplorer and is available from http://www.fjsoft.at/de/.

You will need to install a client on your Android device as well.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client&hl=de

Once this is done you can take screenshots from the program. Tested here with HTC Desire and HTC Flyer. Works great.